# How can i Append Text Line by line to an existing text file in C#

Tags: c#, io, text-files

I have a text file with the following entries:

```
676874463
676844967
676796379
676789975
676760851
676736748
```

I want to read each entry and append data to it as follows:

```
237676874463#
237676844967#
237676796379#
237676789975#
237676760851#
237676736748#
```

I.e., append `237` in front of every entry and `#` at the end of each entry.

here is my code so far:

```
public class Program
        {
            public string fileDoc = @"c:\Users\UNICS\Desktop\Bulk SMS\BafutFormattedWithoutDuplicates.txt";    
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileDoc );

     while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                   // remove duplicates here
                }
```

Can anyone guide me on a way of doing this?

Comment: File.ReadAllLines(), loop & update, File.WriteAllLines()

Comment: Oneliner - `File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(l => $"237{l}#"));`

Comment: Side note: for future questions please demonstrate what you've tried and avoid adding text not directly related to the problem (like "All answers are welcome") and thank you notes (like "Cheers"). I personally don't see why would you *welcome all answers* (wrong/poor quality once that this post collected so far) instead of asking for correct/understandable answers if you really want to add such text.

Answer (score 0):

I´m using StringBuilder and creating a new file where I keep the result you want to see. I'm doing it from BIDS (Bussiness Intelligence Development Studio) but it's c# so it will work for you.

```
using System;

using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ST_d1578e806c274e419063843a63f76441.csproj
{
        public void Main()
        {
            String SomeFileName = @"C:\Users\unmsm_02\Desktop\ExampleTextFile.txt"; // Main FILE
            String AuxFileName = @"C:\Users\unmsm_02\Desktop\ResultTextFile.txt"; // File wher eis the result string

            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(SomeFileName, FileMode.Open))
            using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
            {
                String line;
                while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (line.Length > 1)
                    {

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.Insert(0, "237");
                        sb.Insert(3, line);
                        sb.Insert(line.Length + 3, "#");

                        String line_Aux = sb.ToString();

                        File.AppendAllText(AuxFileName, line_Aux + "\r\n");
                    }
                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success; //FORGET ABOUT THIS, its from the BIDS enviroment, just use the above, and it should work
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**StringBuilder** its pretty useful here, you can just create a String using Insert method with the first parameter being the position where you want to insert, and the second parameter the String you want to insert. After you finish using **insert()** you convert it to a String and in my case save it on **line_Aux**, which is the line that will be saved on the new file.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I thought about reading it into an array and for-loop it to do the edit.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace EditText
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Import text from file to an array.
            string[] myArray = File.ReadAllLines("text1.txt");

            //This is what will be written into the text file.
            string myFileText = "";

            //Loop through the array
            for(int i = 0; i<myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                //Du the change you want here
                string myString = "237" + myArray[i] + "#";

                //Add the result to the string you will write to the file
                myFileText += myString;
                myFileText += Environment.NewLine;
            }

            //Write the text to the file. 
            File.WriteAllText("text1.txt", myFileText);
            //Done

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {
        const string IN_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\in.txt";
        const string OUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\out.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(IN_FILENAME);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUT_FILENAME);

            string inputline = "";
            while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("237" + inputline + "#");
            }

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            reader.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? No explanation, sample that does not work on the same file as OP implied, pointless call to `.Flush()`, using `.Close()` instead of `using` - what kind of recommendation it is?

Comment: @Alexei ,u mean i need a class that  implements IDisposable§

Comment: @user3015410 I don't know what you need. My comment was about the sample in this answer - good practice of using `StreamReader` (and most of the System.IO classes) is `using(var reader = new StreamReader(IN_FILENAME)) { .... }` and not `.Close()` that may be skipped due to exceptions.

Comment: Ok @Alexei your approach makes sense now.